# MathJax broken in "Related" section

Tags: bug, mathjax, design, related-questions

The MathJax/LaTeX rendering seems to be broken for  question titles in the "Related" section. Example from [Show that 1 + $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $I + A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754651/show-that-1-lambda-is-an-eigenvalue-of-i-a):

[image]

(Observed with Safari and Chrome on OS X, Firefox on Windows.)

Comment: Same for me, with TenFourFox (Firefox fork) on OS X.

Comment: Related issue on Japanese.SE meta: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/japanese-text-in-related-box-rendering-strangely

Comment: @snailboat: And solution #1 from http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1557 works here as well.

Comment: Same here, Chrome and Safari on OSX.

Comment: Does it always happen, or only when you "show more comments" before the page is fully loaded?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Always. (Actually there is no "show more comments" on the page that I gave as an example).

Comment: Same here (Chrome on Ubuntu 14).

Comment: Opera is in the race too.

Comment: But Internet Explorer seems to be working well, damn :(

Comment: Chrome on Windows here, broken as well.

Comment: This is the same issue reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278752/titles-with-mathjax-break-in-the-related-questions).

Comment: Thanks for reporting guys and sorry for breaking this.. Fix is going to be live in < 24h

Answer (score 5):

The issue appears to be that the page's CSS causes the links in the sidebar to be `display: flex`, and that changes how the children are treated.  The content is no longer a paragraph-like structure that wraps normally.  Instead, it is a series of boxes that align left to right.  That means that the text before a math item is one box, the math is another, and the text that follows is a third.  By default, these must appear all on one line, so the initial text is wrapped, as is the final text, and the math is smashed in between.  Since these three boxes don't fit in the allowed horizontal space, the three boxes overlap, as in your diagram.

I'm not sure when the change to the CSS occurred, nor what the purpose of it is.  It seems that it might simply be to allow the question title to be centered relative to the score on to its left.

I suspect that a fix would be to put the contents of the `<a>` element into a `<span>` so that there is only one child of the flex container (whose content will wrap normally).